# How to control pipeline failure based on severity of snyk vulnerabilities found?

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, snyk

I'm developing a CI/CD pipeline with Gitlab, and am currently using snyk to run dependency security analysis.  It's working great, but I would like to now implement some logic to allow the pipeline to continue without failure through this step if the vulnerabilities found are under a given threshold.  For example, if there are a few medium severity vulnerabilities found and nothing else, allow this and don't fail the pipeline.  However if there are some medium severity vulnerabilities found and a few high severity vulnerabilities found as well, fail the pipeline due to these high severity vulnerabilities.

I'm using shared Gitlab runners so I'm watching everything run through the online UI.  I've looked into exit codes for the command I'm using (snyk test), but all I've seen is that if any vulnerability is found, the process exits with a "non-zero" exit code.  When I ran snyk test and it found 6 vulnerabilities, three high and three medium severity, the exit code returned with echo $? was 1 (shown below).

Here's a demonstration of the snyk test command and the exit code:

```
$ snyk test

...some vulnerabilities...

Tested 126 dependencies for known vulnerabilities, found 6 vulnerabilities, 32 vulnerable paths.

$ echo $?
1
```

And here's the snyk job defined in my .gitlab-ci.yml in case that's helpful:

```
# TODO Make stage success/failure based on vulnerability severity
snyk-dependency-analysis:
  image: awesomeaiden/custom_snyk
  stage: static_analysis
  only:
    changes:
      - boot-kotlin-svc/**/*
  before_script:
    - cd boot-kotlin-svc
    - export GRADLE_USER_HOME=`pwd`/.gradle
    - export SNYK_TOKEN=$secret_snyk_token
  after_script:
    - cd ..
  variables:
    SNYK_TOKEN: $secret_snyk_token
  script:
    - snyk test
  cache:
    key: "$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME"
    policy: pull
    paths:
      - build
      - .gradle
  allow_failure: true
```

I would love to be able to get highest detected severity level and use it to fail or not fail the pipeline, but I don't see any examples of this online and don't really know if its even possible.

Answer (score 1):

You can add flag `--severity-threshold=low|medium|high`

> With this flag, only vulnerabilities of provided level or higher will
>   be reported

```
snyk test --all-sub-projects --severity-threshold=high
```

Also by default Snyk scans all possible configurations including those used by tests only. To exclude those dependencies you can use `--configuration-matching` flag. Here is example for Gradle projects:

```
snyk test --all-sub-projects --configuration-matching=^(?!test).*
```

this will exclude configurations like: `testCompile`, `testCompileClasspath`, `testRuntimeClasspath`, `testImplementation`, etc

Answer (score 0):

Answer solved, snyk support said you can use the severity threshold option when running the snyk command to ignore vulnerabilities below a certain threshold.

**Snyk Support Answer:**

We do indeed have exit codes, we use exit code 1 for when vulnerabilities are found, 2 for any other failure. You can also use it in conjunction with the --severity-threshold, if for example you only wanted to fail on high severity vulnerabilities.